# Slickgrid use a column to contain the color for each row?

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

Is it possible to add a hidden column to my grid to store a hex color. Then use the value in this column to style the background color of that row?

Comment: Column definitions are coupled to the data but you can have data without a column. Thus, you hide the column by not defining one against the field in question. What condition determines the styling? What events would change the styling? Are you using a data array or a [dataview](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/master/slick.dataview.js)?

Comment: If i understand what you're asking correctly, no condition determines the styling. Every row has a color stored already and the rows just need to render according to that color. No events would change the styling, as in the styling won't need to be 'live'. Using a data view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Styling of an entire row is most intuitively accomplished by providing [metadata](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Providing-data-to-the-grid) to the grid regarding individual rows. When using the Slickgrid Dataview, this becomes slightly more challenging due to the potential need to support grouping, as the groups provide some information via their own `groupItemMetadataProvider`. Similiar to the information [provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591745/assigning-css-style-to-slickgrid-cells) a few options are available. Attempting to format each cell, leaves some visible whitespace and can cause issue with empty cells.

As such, I would provide corresponding css classes for each color you'll be supporting. Setup the `getItemMetadata` to return the respective css for each row.

```
var defaultImpl = dataView.getItemMetadata

var override = function(row){
    
  if(!defaultImpl(row)) {
   var item = dataView.getItem(row)
   /*
     assuming the color is stored similar to #000000 ... strip off the #
     in addition I've prefixed my css classes with 'color_'
   */ 
   var color = item.color ? 'color_' + item.color.substr(1, item.color.length) : ""
   var metadata = item.color ? {cssClasses: color} : null
   return metadata
  }
   return defaultImpl(row)
}

dataView.getItemMetadata = override
```

Note: *Any styling attempts outside the context available to the grid will get wiped upon scrolling*.

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/35tq4a5g/)

Comment: Thanks, this works well. The only problem is that I'm applying classes with WebKit animations and whenever i scroll out of the screen and back again the class seems to be reapplied and the animations then begin again. Is there any way to stop this?

Comment: The grid renders a +/- offset from your "current" viewing index. When scrolling, the rows are dynamically added and removed, as such, a row scrolled into view is essentially always a new DOM element. You can see this behavior within the [post-render example](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example10-async-post-render.html). I'll have to add some animation to my fiddle and mess around with it.

Comment: Feels a bit hackish but you can enable the asyncPostRender and inject a boolean to track whether the row has been rendered previously. Using that property in the metadata provider, you can include/supress the animation css accordingly. Checkout the console statements from [my updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/35tq4a5g/6/) while scrolling through the data.